# Cannot create MySQL table with "if not exists"

Tags: mysql, perl

Here is my code:

`` $STH1000=$DBH->query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '".$dept.$year."' ( `ID` INT( 255 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `URL` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY ( `ID` )) ")
or die "Could not prepare sql statement"; ``

All I'm trying to do is create a table if $dept$year doesn't exist but the way I have it now, it throws errors.

I believe there is a way to create a table is mysql returns an error on a select but I'm not sure how to do that either. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm surprised nobody else prefers variable interpolation over concatenation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$STH1000=$DBH->query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ".$dept.$year." ( `ID` INT( 255 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `URL` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY ( `ID` )) ") or die "Could not prepare sql statement";
```

Table name must not be closed in `''` (but my be optionally closed in ``` `` ```).

Answer (score 1):

just remove quotes from `'".$dept.$year."'` as `".$dept.$year."`

your query will be like this

```
$STH1000=$DBH->query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ".$dept.$year." ( `ID` INT( 255 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `URL` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY ( `ID` )) ") or die "Could not prepare sql statement";
```

Comment: I don't think your correction propagated to your code section.

Comment: @LenJaffe ya by mistake i didnt remove quotes from query, now check